# How do build an Azure Devops Pipeline with Fluent Migrator task?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, fluent-migrator

I have been using Fluent Migrator (version 3.2.1) for some time and in my Visual Studio environment I use dotnet-fm to migrate or rollback my migrations. This is all great but now I want to automate this and use Azure Devops Pipelines to run the migration commands but I don't know how and where to start. 
Has anyone done this and could be kind enough to point me in the right direction, maybe with some examples. I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am wanting to do this too

Answer (score 3):

> How do build an Azure Devops Pipeline with Fluent Migrator task?

Not sure if what I did is exactly what you want. You could check if the information below is helpful.

According to the document [Quickstart of fluentmigrator](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/quickstart.html?tabs=runner-dotnet-fm):

1. Created a .net core library project and add the package `FluentMigrator`, `FluentMigrator.Runner`, `FluentMigrator.Runner.SQLite`, `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`.
2. Create a file called `20180430_AddLogTable.cs`.
3. Build the project.
4. Open a cmd window, switch path to the project folder, and then execute the command line:

   ```
   dotnet tool install -g FluentMigrator.DotNet.Cli
   ```
5. After install the `FluentMigrator.DotNet.Cli` and execute the command line:

   ```
   dotnet fm migrate -p sqlite -c "Data Source=test.db" -a ".\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\test.dll"
   ```

It works fine on my local side.

Then, submit the solution to the Azure devops repo, create a pipeline with following tasks:

1. NuGet tool installer
2. NuGet Restore
3. Dotnet build
4. Command line task with following scripts:

   ```
   cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/test/test

   dotnet tool install -g FluentMigrator.DotNet.Cli

   dotnet fm migrate -p sqlite -c "Data Source=test.db" -a ".\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\test.dll"
   ```

It works the same:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And yes it has helped me get halfway through. I'm trying to run the migrations from within a release pipeline but can't figure out what kind of agent to use. My datebase is on premise and I have set up an agent on the server, but I'm not able to get a network connection to the server. Is there another way to do this? the install script works fine but not the dotnet-fm commands. thats where I get the network service exceptions. Any clues?